# How to tell Safari/Firefox to always use the expanded Print Dialog?

Tags: macos, safari, preferences, osx-leopard, printdialog

Mac Os X has 2 forms for the Print dialog - one collapsed and one expanded. Is there a command that would set Safari and Firefox to always use the expanded print dialog? Everywhere I searched I came to the same answer that doesn't work:

```
defaults write -g PMPrintingExpandedStateForPrint -bool TRUE
```

I tried that setting, verified that was successfully written in the preferences files but I still get the collapsed printing-dialog on Firefox and Safari. 
Is there a way to setup things so that Safari and Firefox never show the collapsed Print dialog?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`defaults write -g` writes to the global preferences domain, over which the application domains take precedence. If you want this to work in Safari or Firefox, then use their preferences domains instead, e.g. `defaults write com.apple.Safari PMPrintingExpandedStateForPrint -bool TRUE`.